# positivity of real part of Gaussian periods

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $n$ be any integer $\geq 3$ and $k \in {\mathbb Z}^{\times}_n$ of multiplicative order $\alpha \geq 3$ (fixed). Let $G = \langle k \rangle \leq {\mathbb Z}^{\times}_n$ and $S(G,i)$ denote the Gaussian period for any $i \in {\mathbb Z}_n$ defined by $S(G, i) = \sum_{\tau = 0}^{\alpha -1} \omega^{ik^{\tau}}_n$. I am trying to wonder if real part of $S(G,i)$ is positive for some $i$ and if so, any good upper bound to estimate this while $i$ vary over all elements in ${\mathbb Z}_n$.

Comment: You had better tell us how you are defining the "Gaussian period" $S(G,i)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: [Wikipedia helps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_period).

Comment: @Alex, it's always preferable for a question to be self-contained.

Comment: Note that if $n$ is a prime, and if $k$ is a primitive root modulo $n$, then there is only one Gaussian period, and it's just the sum of all the primitive $n$th roots of unity, which is $-1$. So in that case the real part is always negative.

Comment: Moreover, if $n$ is prime, and $k$ generates the quadratic residues, then both Gaussian periods have real part $-1/2$. So, have you actually calculated any examples, to get some kind of feel for how the real part goes?

Comment: @Gerry : I just edited the question for clarity. The problem is to vary $n$ and $\alpha$ fixed.

Comment: @Gerry : The case of primitive root or quadratic residues are not too helpful as again $\alpha \geq 3$ and fixed. In fact I am looking for a fixed range $3 \leq \alpha \leq 8$ and $n$ is arbitrary. For example while $\alpha=3$ and $k \leq [n/2]$, $S(G,1)$ is positive as $\omega^{k^2}_n$ is far away from $-1$ mod $n$.

Comment: Are you sure about that? For $\alpha=3$, $n=19$, we have $k=7$, and the real part of $S(G,1)$ is $\cos(2\pi/19)+\cos(14\pi/19)+\cos(22\pi/19)=-0.61$ to two decimals.

Comment: @Gerry : my bad. I need either $k$ or $k^2$ to lie in [-[n/4], [n/4]]. Then $\cos({2\pi k/n})$ or $\cos({2\pi k^2/n})$ would be positive, the negative one is smaller than $\cos({2\pi/n})$.

Comment: Maybe you should have a good long think about what exactly you are after, and then come back and edit your question accordingly. No one wants to follow long strings of comments.